# How can I remove a property from state object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here are properties of state object:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState({
    key1: 'apple',
    key2: 'watermelon',
    key3: 'banana',
  });
```

I wonder, how I can delete specific property from this state object by handling delete?

```
 const handleDelete = (e) => { }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  When you update state with `setItems`, what doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way: duplicate the object (so React notices the change), [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the key (maybe this is the JavaScript feature you were missing), and set the state.

```js
const handleDelete = (e) => {
  const newItems = {...items};
  delete newItems.key2; // or whichever key you want
  setItems(newItems);
}
```

I'm curious whether there's an `Object` helper to do this all in one line.

@Wyck found a cleaner way, which uses the "rest" aspect of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const handleDelete = (e) => {
  const {key2, ...newItems} = items; // newItems gets all but key2
  setItems(newItems);
}
```

Comment: or `let {key2, ...newItems} = items;`

Comment: Thanks. I still like the first one. It's simple and easy.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the `callback function` from `setState` And then return the new object.

```
setItems(prevState => {
    const {key2, ...newItems} = prevState;    
    return newItems;
});
```

If you use this method, wrap your `deleteElement` in a `useCallback` hook and add `items` to the list of dependencies:

```
const deleteElement = useCallback((e) => { … }, [items]);
```

Combine this with the @edemaine solution ☺️

Comment: bad quotes - you might want to investigate how they got in there.